# Datatables Search Automagically Submit with GET Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have a website where I'm using datatables and I want to automagically submit a search from a GET variable. I have no trouble getting the GET variable into the search input, I just can't seem to submit it. It's not a form, so `submit()` is worthless. I'm trying to have jQuery trigger an ENTER, but it's not working. Here's the javascript at the bottom of my php file where the datatable is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#responses-table').DataTable({
        dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf','print'
        ]
    });
    $('input').val("<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>");
    $('input').focus();

    // this actually does nothing
    var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    e.which = 13;
    e.keyCode = 13;
    $("input").trigger(e);
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a submit button that you could register a click on?

Comment: No, Datatables just has a input in a div, hence my conundrum.

Comment: Ah I see, that is difficult, perhaps check out http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/259/trigger-the-search or https://datatables.net/reference/event/search to see about triggering it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a case of "*can't see the forest for the trees*" :)

```
table.search("<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>").draw();
```

or

```
$(".dataTables_filter input").val("<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>").keyup();
```

both will fill the input box with the `$_GET` value and perform the search.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I had tried the first after setting the val thinking that `search()` would get it automagically.